# Include Typescript interface props entirely if another prop exists

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following interfaces:

```js
interface MyDialogProps extends DialogProps {
  title: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  action?: React.ReactNode;
  form?: boolean;
}

interface MyFormProps <Values extends object> {
  values: Values;
  onSubmit: (values: Values) => Promise <{}> ;
}
```

I need a union/intersection `type` between those two interfaces that expresses the fact that `values` and `onSubmit` are both required if and only if `form` is provided or `true`.

Comment: From what context ```form``` property should be provided? Do you want to construct a type based on another type or maybe you pass some object of type ```MyDialogProps``` to some function and it should return a different type based on the value of the ```form``` property of this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  We check the value of the generic and return a different type depending on whether or not `form` is defined as `true`.

```
type FormPropsUnion<Values extends { form?: boolean }> =
    Values extends { form: true }
    ? MyFormProps<Values>
    : Partial<MyFormProps<Values>>
```

When `form` is `true`, `values` and `onSumbit` are required and when `form` is `false` or `undefined`, those fields are optional.

Be aware that typescript is checking the **type** of `form`, not the **value** of `form`, so it is important that you use appropriate generics in any function where you want to return a refined type. The type for `FormPropsUnion<MyDialogProps>` will have optional properties because we don't know that `form` will always be true.

But if we are dealing with a specific instance of `MyDialogProps`, that's when we can use a generic `P extends MyDialogProps` to get the right type depending on the value of `form`.

```
declare function makeProps<P extends MyDialogProps>(props: P): FormPropsUnion<P>;

const one = makeProps({title: "", form: true}); // required fields 

const two = makeProps({title: ""}); // optional fields
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/4w19Gw)